# Bootcamp - Stuck on "Partitioning Disk..."

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, mojave

When attempting to add a Windows 10 (April 2018, build 1803) partition to my 2019 iMac, I get stuck on "Partitioning disk..." perpetually. [image: Partitioning disk...]

When I look at Disk Utility, the `OSXRESERVED` and `BOOTCAMP` partitions appear:

[image: Disk Utility partitions]

My iMac is running the latest stable release of macOS, `10.14.5 (18F132)`. Is there a known bug/solution to this problem?

Comment: Just making sure, you waited enough time before quitting out of Bootcamp? I had to wait for around 20 - 30 mins for it to finish partitioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple released a patch for my issue here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2007